# Rewriting a quadratic function

Tags: functions

i have to find domain of this function $f(x) = \log(10+3x-x^2)$ can i rewrite this as 
$\log(x^2-3x-10)$? I found the domain but is not  the same for 2 forms of function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $10 + 3x - x^2 = (x+2)(5-x)$ and $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$

Note that $\log(10 + 3x - x^2) = \log\left(-(x^2 - 3x - 10)\right)\ne \log(x^2 - 3x - 10)$ as $\log(a) \ne \log(-a)$